# can you change code values on a MCU while its running

Tags: microcontroller

i want to run a MCU and be able to change values in the code while its running just to give an example i have a position sensor with a homing pulse the mcu is programed to only send a trigger pulse out 10 pulses before the homing pulse but i want to be able to adjust that (on the fly) so to speak so as the machine is running adjust it till its perfect so almost like an offset i thought of using a dual bank memory MCU and i just also want to find out if anybody has any experience with dual bank memory MCUs and are there maybe any MCUs that support such a function as live code adjustment or if there is just a simpler way im not seeing here

i am very new here and i dont have a lot of experience with this sort of stuff
any help would be really great thanks

Comment: `microcontroller` tag requires you specify the part you're using.  This is not a hardware recommendation site.  This is also not a design round table.

Comment: If you want to change parameters on the fly you make them variables in the code and provide a live interface to the firmware (uart, etc) that you can use to change that on the fly.  You could try to do some form of self-modifying-code while being executed and you would do that by running in ram, but so far that makes no sense.  Bank flipping is highly likely not going to get that for you while actively running, would be a pause, and would make no sense when the code under test can be run in ram.

Comment: Live parameter changes are done with variables in the code basically not by run-time recompiling and changing the code. I cant think of real situations where you would want to even attempt that and in those cases you would instead perform different test runs with the various binaries each is own test not a live modification.

Comment: thank you very much old_timer for this info it really helped the dual memory banks kinda seemed a bit over kill but i wasn't aware it could be done in code ill definitely look more into that do you think its possible to code it in such a way that i can change it in a kind of graph manner so example 200 pulses a minute it retards the signal 1 second and at 400 pulses advances it by .5 seconds if you understand what i mean so adjust it based on a changing input value from a sensor i dont know if that makes sense to anyone.. XD

Answer (score 0):

These are quite a lot questions in one and not all is fully clear to me.

Regarding the MCU:

- I'm using ESP32 primarily, which is cheap and supports bluetooth and wifi.

Regarding the question of "on-the-fly" adjustment, I see at least three different options with increasing complexity and knowledge required:

- Use an I/O port that can implement an A/D converter. With a potentiometer you can than fine tune the clocking.
- Implementing a web server with wifi on the MCU: this way you can use your phone's web-browser to send configuration information.
- Use OTA (Over The Air) to flash the controller with new data and possibly new instruction set.

You can find many good tutorials using the ESP32 or Arduino-family on youtube.